# Is it possible to edit a node in-place in any javascript tree visualization toolkit (preferably InfoVis)?

Tags: javascript, visualization, edit-in-place, infovis

I had earlier asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484058/609074) asking how/what to use to show to render data in a top-down tree like fashion.

I also stumbled up this post: [Graph visualization library in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034/graph-visualization-code-in-javascript) where the following toolkits were suggested for visualization:

- [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/)
  Sophisticated graphing with nice physics and eyecandy.
- [Canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/)
  JS renderer for Graphviz graphs
- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)
  Beautiful and powerful Flash based graph drawing
- [Graph JavaScript framework, version 0.0.1](http://snipplr.com/view/1950/graph-javascript-framework-version-001/)
  Basic graph layout
- [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)
  Sophisticated graph visualization language
- [JavaScript Canvas Hyperbolic Tree](http://hypertree.woot.com.ar/)
  Small and flexible script
- [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/)
  Jit, an interactive, multi-purpose graph drawing and layout framework
- [JS Graph It](http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/)
  Promising project using HTML5
- [jsPlumb](http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/index.html)
  jQuery plug-in for creating interactive connected graphs
- [jssvggraph](http://github.com/jackrusher/jssvggraph)
  Lightweight yet nice graph layouter
- [Moo Wheel](http://labs.unwieldy.net/moowheel/)
  Interactive JS representation for connections and relations
- [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph)
  Python Graph Visualization
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html)
  Graphical Toolkit for Visualization (JavaScript)

I decided to pick the InfoVis Toolkit's SpaceTree visualization. However, the issue that's been nagging me is no library seems to come with in-place editing of node text...or at least that's what I feel. Our requirement is that when a user clicks a node (or right-clicks and selects an option etc.,) the node text should be editable in place.

Most of the toolkits didn't allow it - they seem to be a read-only visualization/view of the underlying data (except for JS Graph It - however it doesn't have any *layouting* built in and that's important).

I don't mind changing my choice of toolkit and was wondering if anyone knew either how to edit the text of a node in-place in InfoVis or would recommend another toolkit for that?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though its late, I would answer your question for others having similar requirement.

In infoVis you can simply change the node.name to edit the text of node.

```
onRightClick: function( node, eventInfo, e){
    node.name = "Changed the name in-place"
    fd.plot(); // fd is an instance of ForceDirected visualization 
}
```

Here I am changing node text in-place on right-click event, you can change that as per your need.